# Can´t access to external database from Docker container

Tags: macos, docker, networking

I have a simple Docker Compose file for PHP and Nginx.
PHP app needs access to a external database (not in Docker).

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services: 
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        container_name: nginx
        ports: 
            - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - ./docker/nginx/core:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./:/var/www/
            - ./docker/nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx/
        links:
            - php

    php:
        build: .
        container_name: php-fpm
        environment:
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_enable=1
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/
            - ./docker/php/logs:/var/log/
```

Our database access is restricted by IP. Docker host (my Mac) has access without problem.

If I create **ssh tunnel** on my host and use host IP address from container, all is OK. But I want do it without using a SSH tunnel (we have many databases on different projects).

Comment: I think that the problem might be related to the fact that each Docker container has its own internal IP address and your DBMS might be detecting it as source of the connection (and not the host IP). There are several networking settings and mode, like "host" mode, where the docker shares the host network (https://docs.docker.com/network/host/). Maybe one of these modes help you out.